# Why did the Water Spirit destroy the ship when Elsa and Anna's parents were going to Ahtohallan?

Tags: frozen, frozen-ii

Elsa and Anna found the destroyed ship while they were on their adventure. It was in the Black Sea and not the North Sea, as they were told. It's explained in the movie that their parents were trying to find Ahtohallan, to find the truth about Elsa's powers.

Also, the spirits of the nature were angry because of what King Runeard did. Later in the movie, we learn that going to Ahtohallan was actually the answer to all problems.

So, why did the Water Spirit try to prevent that? Rey Agnarr and Reina Iduna finding Ahtohallan was actually what the Water Spirit and everyone needed to calm down, because Agnarr would probably destroy the dam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible explanations:

1. The Water Spirit **indiscriminately sinks and drowns** all trespassers. For evidence of this, consider how it treated the Ice Spirit (Elsa) during their first contact in the raging ocean waters.
2. The Water Spirit **identified the ship as Arendellian** or that it held the son of King Runeard (Agnarr) within. It expressed its anger accordingly.
3. The Water Spirit **was not aware** of the Ice Spirit's parentage, the presence of a Northuldra (Iduna), or what the passengers of the vessel sought to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

The water spirit looks a llt like a traditional Nordic folklore, the Kelpie it is a water spirit that takes the form of a horse and enjoys drowning its victims.
Also Agnarr's father caused disorder between nature and civilization that lasted for 34 years and would be reason enough for to kill Agnarr and Iduna despite their own positive connection to nature.